# How to convert a column in pandas data frame which has special characters in its values and also None as a value?

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, data-analysis

I have a column named Value in my **jeopardy** data frame. I am giving the column here

[image]

I want to remove the '$' and the ',' symbols and also convert the whole column into a float dtype.
I used the following code:

```
jeopardy['Value'].replace(regex=True, inplace=True, to_replace=r'[$,]', value=r'')
jeopardy['Value'] = jeopardy['Value'].astype(float)
```

which gave me the following error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'None'

I even tried this

```
jeopardy['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(jeopardy['Value'],errors='coerce')
```

which converts the whole column values into Nan.

I want to convert the whole `jeopardy['Value']` column into a float dtype by removing the '$' and ','

Comment: What is `print (jeopardy['Value'].head().tolist())` after `jeopardy['Value'].replace(regex=True, inplace=True, to_replace=r'[$,]', value=r'')` ?

Comment: Maybe need `jeopardy['Value'] = jeopardy['Value'].str.strip().astype(float)`

Comment: I tried using the using the `jeopardy['Value].head().astype(float)` after `jeopardy['Value'].replace(regex=True, inplace=True, to_replace=r'[$,]', value=r'')` it worked for normal string like '$200' but when it comes to `None` values it is throwing an error.

Comment: Hmm, what about `jeopardy['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(jeopardy['Value'].str.strip(),errors='coerce')` instead `jeopardy['Value'] = jeopardy['Value'].str.strip().astype(float)` ?

Comment: It is not removing the '$' and ',' the characters. Basically, no change is happening.

Comment: Can you try `jeopardy['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(jeopardy['Value'].replace(regex=True,  to_replace=r'[$,]', value=r'').str.strip(),errors='coerce')` ?

Comment: Yes `jeopardy['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(jeopardy['Value'].replace(regex=True,  to_replace=r'[$,]', value=r'').str.strip(),errors='coerce')` is working all of them are converted to float and no issues with the`None` Values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need espace `$` because special regex character and pass to `to_numeric`:

```
jeopardy['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(jeopardy['Value'].replace('[\$,]', '',regex=True), 
                                  errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Well the one above as well as this one `jeopardy['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(jeopardy['Value'].replace(regex=True,  to_replace=r'[$,]', value=r'').str.strip(),errors='coerce')` both of them are working.